# Does google TV support C2DM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-tv

is C2DM works in Google Tv ? assuming it have android 2.2+ and Android market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.  The next version of Google TV will be running Honeycomb.

http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/08/android-google-tv/

Comment: so does this mean that it will work now (with the current ver) or after the update it will work?